# Can't read file data in Matlab with textread

Tags: matlab, file

I'm trying to read a **.samp** file's data in Matlab with the **textread** function. I want to put each **row** of the file in an array. This is the .samp file:

```
@CATEGORY:GENERAL
@IMAGE:2012-04-26-Muenchen-Tunnel_4K0G0010.JPG
# format: id type center.x center.y size.width size.height angle
0 30 1319 2338 35 11 56.451578
1 30 1337 2350 42 14 57.817368
2 30 224 3556 61 20 136.967797
```

When I try to run this command:

```
[id, type, x, y, width, height, angle] = textread('data', '%d%d%d%d%d%d%f', 'headerlines', 3);
```

it doesn't work and gives an error:

> Error using dataread
>
> Trouble reading integer from file (row 1, field > 1) ==> %  CB =
> DATA(OBJ, 'get_callbacks') returns a
>
> Error in textread (line 174)
>
> [varargout{1:nlhs}]=dataread('file',varargin{:}); %#ok

How should I type the command to run correctly? and what should I do afterwards to put each row (line) in a separate array?

Comment: well, first you should use `textscan` as `textread` is outdated. Next, I noticed you have not specified your delimiter which is a space, so I suggest you do that and it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the full file path as the first argument. For me, putting `data` in `C:\Users\MyUsername\` and then calling

```
 [id, type, x, y, width, height, angle] = textread('C:\Users\MyUsername\data',...
                                                   '%d%d%d%d%d%d%f',...
                                                   'headerlines', 3);
```

was pretty much enough to make it work. However, Matlab [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) suggests switching `textread` to `textscan`, so you should probably consider that.

As for the second part of your question: do you actually expect to have just three lines in you file? If not, you could put all your column vectors into a matrix and access horizontal vectors by slicing:

```
M = [id type x y width height angle];
M(1,:) %  first line of your file
```

However, if you do expect to have just three lines, you could use

```
vec1 = [id(1) type(1) x(1) y(1) width(1) height(1) angle(1)];
vec2 = [id(2) type(2) x(2) y(2) width(2) height(2) angle(2)];
vec3 = [id(3) type(3) x(3) y(3) width(3) height(3) angle(3)];
```

Comment: the headlines option is used to ignore the first 3 lines (known as headers) of the file - so the parser only parse the rest of the file since the headers usually have a special format: i.e. All Strings.

Comment: @GameOfThrows sure, it's just that the asker wants to put all rows into separate arrays, and I don't know if that's possible or reasonable when you don't know how many rows you expect. The example file has three rows of data and appears to be related to an image, so I assumed the three rows might be for different RGB channels or whatnot - in which case the data will have just 3 rows every time.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I did put the full path as you suggested and it worked. this file is for an image and had only three lines. But there are many more of these files with much more lines. So you say I should import each file and do the separation line by line? Or there is quicker way?

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad it depends on what you want to do with the separate rows. How do you want to use them?

Comment: the rows are the information of bounding boxes around vehicles in a satellite image. I want to draw the bounding boxes on the image to separate the vehicles so that I can create training dataset for a deep neural network.

Comment: @Hadi I don't think you have to put them into separate arrays for that. You could just iterate over the `y` dimension of the matrix `M` (see my answer) . Or, to take up less memory, you could just use a loop like `for i = 1:1:length(id)` and then do something with `type(i)`, `x(i)` etc. every lop iteration.